# Android Studio icon fixation

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-icons

I'm working on a project for a cookbook recipe app. The issue I'm facing is that when I enter the description for the recipe in the app. The icon moves with the text. Is there a way to fix the icon at a specific position in the layout using **xml** or **code** in the **activity**?

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]
Here is the code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cardViewList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/trPersonsTimeDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/recipe_icon"
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/recipe_1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Beschreibung"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trPersonsTimeDetails"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:background="@drawable/timer" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/trPersonsTimeDetails"
                android:text="Zeit"
                android:textSize="16dp" />


        </TableRow>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: does your icon have a standard 24dp x 24dp size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For imageView you should use parameter `src` instead of `background` and for the scaling issue you need `scaleType="fitCenter"` just like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_icon"
    android:layout_width="33dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/recipe_1" />
```

Comment: android:layout_height="33dp" fixed it !

Answer (score 2):

you could just set a defined size to 24dp x 24dp and change the scaletype to fit center

[image]